# Proof of limit $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = 1$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

How do you prove that the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = 1$$
I have tried doing this:
Let$$y = \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$
$$\ln(y) =\lim_{x\to0} (x*(-\ln(x)))$$
$$\ln(y) = \lim_{x\to0}-x\ln(x)$$
$$\ln(y) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(x)}{-1/x}$$
This is where I'm stuck. The top limit is DNE, as well as the bottom limit, because the left and right sides do not equal each other. So how do you prove this limit?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the limit has to be $x\to0^+$

Now, applying L'Hospital's

$\displaystyle\ln y=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln x}{-\dfrac1x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac1x}{\dfrac1{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}x$ as $x\ne0$ as $x\to0^+$

Comment: Yes, I understand. However, why does wolfram give the answer as 1? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+approaches+0+of+%281%2Fx%29%5Ex&lk=4&num=1

Comment: @VishwaIyer, we have $$\ln y=0\implies y=e^0=\cdots$$

Comment: I understand. But how would you evaluate the limit, if it was as x approaches 0, from both sides, not just the right one?

Comment: @VishwaIyer How would you solve the limit $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\sqrt x\right)$ from both sides?

Comment: @VishwaIyer, see the plot : http://symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D(x%5Cln(x))

Comment: @GitGud the limit does not exist. So for this problem, why does the limit equal one, shouldn't it be DNE?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the link you posted uses l'hopital's rule, which is the trival way to solve this. However, you shouldn't be able to use it because the limit exists for only the right side.

Comment: @GitGud Apprantly Wolfram says that $$\lim_{x\to0}(\sqrt{x})$$ is $0$, except that the left limit DNE, so how can that be possible?

Comment: @VishwaIyer By definition one has $$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\sqrt x\right)=0\\ \Updownarrow\\ \forall \delta >0\exists \epsilon >0 \forall x\in [0, +\infty[\left(|x-0|<\varepsilon \implies |\sqrt x-0|<\delta\right).$$
Can you prove that the statement on the line above is true?

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate $y$ using $a^b=e^{b\log a}$, so
$$
y=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac1{x}\right)^x=
\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{x\log\frac1{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{-x\log x }
=\exp\big(-\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log x\big)=e^0=1
$$
for continuity of $e^{-t}$ and because $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log x=0$.